# PHP urldecode issue

Tags: php

I'm posting the below javascript endcodeURI value via jquery to a PHP script, there I use urldecode and store the value in the db, but the '>' symbol is not stored.

```
testid=174742228&VI-42=zdddfsdsdf%3Edsdfsdfs%3Efsdfsdfs&

+------+-----------+-----+-----+------------------------------+------+
| id   | testid    | sec | qid | ans                          | img  |
+------+-----------+-----+-----+------------------------------+------+
| 6510 | 174742228 | VI  |  42 | zdddfsdsdf dsdfsdfs fsdfsdfs | NULL |
+------+-----------+-----+-----+------------------------------+------+

foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
    $flds = explode("-", $k);
    if (count($flds) == 3) {
        $datai = array($flds[0], $flds[1], $flds[2], $testid, urldecode(mysql_escape_string($v)));
        $resi = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO result (sec, img, qid, testid, ans) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $resi->execute($datai);
    } else {
        $data = array($flds[0], $flds[1], $testid, urldecode(mysql_escape_string($v)));
        $res = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO result (sec, qid, testid, ans) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $res->execute($data);
    }   
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. What's your sql query that stores the data? 2. which column type does `ans` have?

Comment: Can you show the code for creating the query? The error might lie in there.

Comment: Probably need to show code on how you are inserting it, and how you are urldecoding it in order to help find the problem.

Comment: `foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
    $flds = explode("-", $k);
    if (count($flds) == 3) {
        $datai = array($flds[0], $flds[1], $flds[2], $testid, urldecode(mysql_escape_string($v)));
        $resi = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO result (sec, img, qid, testid, ans) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $resi->execute($datai);
    } else {
        $data = array($flds[0], $flds[1], $testid, urldecode(mysql_escape_string($v)));
        $res = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO result (sec, qid, testid, ans) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $res->execute($data);
    }   
}`

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting code as a comment. :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if any of this will fix your problem, but there are a few problems in your code:

1. `mysql_escape_string` is deprecated, you should use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string).
2. You should urldecode **before** escaping (e.g.: `mysql_real_escape_string(urldecode($str));`).
3. You **don't even have to escape anything**. You are using prepared statements (most probably PDO from the syntax). PDO will automatically escape values with placeholders for you.
4. You may be double-decoding. If the query string you posted is sent directly to PHP as request body, it is automatically decoded. Therefore, you may be urldecoding an already decoded URL.
5. The facts that you are referencing `$testid` directly (instead of `$_POST['test_id']`) makes me think that you may be using **register_globals**. It may not be the case, but just to make sure.

Other than that, the code seems fine and shouldn't make the `>` symbols disappear. Check your MySQL column type and/or try [var_dumping](http://php.net/var_dump) $_POST and check what you've got there.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried var_dump, the `>` symbols are missing. What would be the problem? I can see ajax is sending the correct encoded data to the php script `testid=723006807&VI-28=adads%3Easdasda%3EAsdasd%3EAsdasda%3Easdasda&`

Answer (score 0):

Try reversing the order of `urldecode(mysql_escape_string($v))`. You are escaping the data before it's converted into what is actually going into the database.